# in regression (logistic), how can you convert MNAR (missing not at random) observations within a variable that isn't categorical?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, missing-data

Assume i have a binary outcome that has say, 5 input variables.  for one of the variables, it's a numeric variable, but has 20% missing not at random (e.g. if they are missing the variable, it's very telling about the outcome, and is likely predictive).
  If it was categorical (say, "male", "female"), I could easily change the NAs to something like "other/missing".  But how do I do that for a numeric?  When i break it out as a categorical, what do I replace it with within the numerical group?

is that possible?

Comment: Perhaps leave NA in the numeric variable and add a 2nd variable denoting missingness.

Comment: This question may be better suited for the statistics overflow considering its now code related

Comment: but what do you convert the NA's too? @JonSpring

Comment: You could probably just fill in the mean or median. If you leave it as `NA` it'll probably mean those observations get dropped from the regression entirely.

Comment: my intuition is to impute them to zero, and create an interaction term potentially. hmm.. not sure. that's kinda my issue.

Comment: @CoreyPembleton i don't have enough leveling there to post this there :-/

Comment: @Marius i think your suggestion of mapping to the mean is a solid recommendation!  i will do accordingly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggested proposal for maximizing informative value in a simple way, in logistic regression, for MNAR (missing not at random), is to recode the NA's into another categorical/binary variable and change the NA's to the median value, thus the binary flag variable can/should capture the meaningful variance of that variable MNAR observations.